# How to incorporate the usage of AND when querying onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute in the MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to query multiple values when it comes to onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute in MS Graph API.

I'm able to query this one:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr1'
```

But I want to query more values than attr1, but I haven't managed to get it to work.

I've tried queries, such as these two:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr1' and 'attr2' and 'attr3'

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute13 eq 'attr1'&$onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr2'&$onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'attr3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax should be

```
$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute13 eq 'attr1' and onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute13 eq 'attr2' and onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute13 eq 'attr3'
```

one filter param to include all conditions, and each condition is full - field eq 'value'

Comment: The following shows up when I query what you wrote: 

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}

Comment: that means no data match to your filter. maybe you should use _or_ instead of _and_ so ANY of the conditions will return result?